# Postgres Materialized views syntax

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, postgresql-9.3

I upgraded postgres from 9.1 to 9.3 for materialized views. 
Now, I am trying to create a view using the following syntax:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW matview_test_view AS select * from invoices;
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MATERIALIZED"
LINE 1: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW matview_test_view AS select * from ...
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the 9.3 instance? `SELECT version();`

Comment: Turns out that it was still talking to the 9.1 server. Started 9.3 and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks sensible. That error is what I'd expect if you were actually using an older server. So I'd suggest verifying that you are in fact connecting to the expected server:

```
SELECT version();

SHOW data_directory;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was still running the 9.1 server, hence I got the error. Works fine when I restarted the server 9.3